# Microsoft ADFS with Powershell - Add Relying party trust with Secure Hash Algorithm SHA-1

Tags: powershell, saml, windows-server-2012, adfs, sha

I'm currently trying to create a Relying Party Trust which is configured to have the Secure Hash Algorithm "SHA-1" with the following PowerShell code (Windows Server 2012):

```
Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name 'SAMLTest' -MetadataFile 'C:\Users\ap2admin\Desktop\SAML_MetaData.xml' -SignatureAlgorithm  'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'
```

unfortunately the code ignores the attribute and creates a relying party trust with SHA-256 algorithm.

any suggestions how to get it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I managed to make this operation work, although I'm still not sure why my original code didn't.
here is the code for adding a new Relying party trust with SHA-1

```
Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name 'SAMLTest' -MetadataFile 'C:\Users\ap2admin\Desktop\SAML_MetaData.xml'
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName 'SAMLTest' -SignatureAlgorithm 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'
```